# How to disable programmatically Eclipse "Password Required" dialog?

Tags: eclipse, passwords, dialog, required

I get "Password Required" eclipse dialog when i try to connect to some remote server with wrong user name and password.

The strange thing is that the Eclipse platform first gets my response and show the dialog and only then it reaches my try/catch block.

I just want to disable this dialog manually or programmatically.

Comment: Is it the password storage dialog from Eclipse! When yes: What OS you're using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code before you send a request:

```
// use default authenticator in order to catch
// all connectivity exceptions and provide appropriate
// error message
// prevents eclipse from displaying "Password Required" dialog
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() 
{
});
```

Comment: messing with Authenticator would affect all other plugins so this should not be done.

Answer (score 11):

Window --> Preferences -- > General --> Network Connections --> Set Active Provider to Direct

Comment: What about Internet access **via proxy**? I don't have problems with `Direct`. I **must** use `Manual` (or `Native`) so that Eclipse connects to the Internet via proxy in the office. And it keeps on prompting "Password Required" even with `Manual` and all credentials for authentication provided. Any update for this case?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Window Menu -> Preferences
2. select General->Network Connections
3. This page will have Active Provider as Manual/Native in drop down .
4. Change it to "Direct"